# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't turn off (halt) under ESXi 5.0U1

Tags: 12.04, server, shutdown

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 x64 (server) on my ESXi 5.0U1 server and it's mostly working fine except when I try to turn off the system using the halt command (/sbin/halt) it says "Powering off..." but the virtual machine never actually turns off.

If I use the VMware tools to shutdown the host it does turn off, but /sbin/halt worked in every other Ubuntu version and also works in Debian so it should work now...

Anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT:  After further testing, "halt -p", "shutdown -h now", and "poweroff" all correctly power-off the machine but "halt" (without parameters) does not.  However, in Ubuntu 10.04, "halt" did power-off the machine.  Is this simply a difference between the two versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

The following command works for me

```
shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem on Ubuntu Server 12.04 every command except halt works fine. I have also tried this: [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer) but without any effect. So the best thing is use different command
or just create a simple script with
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1044866/

and save it as ex. powerdown in `/usr/local/bin`