# Ubuntu hangs at Plymouth screen during shutdown

Tags: shutdown, hp, plymouth

Sometimes(rather many times), when I shutdown using the menu option >> Shutdown, the system hangs at a Purple screen with dots. I have waited for 10 mins, but then it becomes clear that i need to do a hard shutdown using power button.

I am using Ubuntu  64 bit AMD edition(12.04.1 LTS) on HP Proliant Microserver(N40L) with OEM hardware.

Comment: What ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ia m using 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: updated original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, there is a bug with some graphic cards [you can check here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/987220), I've tryed [kubahaha's way](https://askubuntu.com/a/127022/92745) and it worked for me:

Type in terminal:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
3. Change it to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
4. Save and close the file.
5. Finally, in terminal: `sudo update-grub`

Similar questions with this bug:

- [Ubuntu 12.04 does not Shut Down at all and gets Stuck on 3 or 4 dots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161864/ubuntu-12-04-does-not-shut-down-at-all-and-gets-stuck-on-3-or-4-dots)
- [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)

Comment: ok, I will try it out and report my result here.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have you tried to see what happens when you press F8 when the purple screen appears? You will be able to see where it hangs.

Edit: this can be made into a comment if someone wishes.