# Shutdown problem in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, grub2, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I'm getting a serious bug:

When I try to shutdown my system, my screen goes blank but my CPU fan keeps running, i.e. the processor is still working but I am not able to see anything on my screen. I need to power off my machine for a complete shutdown.

I am using a desktop with an Intel P4 processor. I found a solution on the internet involving modifying the GRUB config file. But even after doing so I wasn't able to eliminate the issue.

Comment: What steps id you follow to modify the GRUB configuration? Did you run `sudo update-grub` afterwards?

Comment: [This solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/127022/22949) will likely work for you. By the way, this should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) if it hasn't been already. (You may want to check the bugs [listed here](http://askubuntu.com/a/130799/22949).)