# Ubuntu 12.04 does not shutdown

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 desktop.

It worked fine, but after the last update, the system does not shutdown.

It gets stuck with the last line on the screen being:

```
unmounted /kernel/debug
```

I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. It restarts the machine. Then at the grub screen, I choose to hard shutdown the machine.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: please see is it useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer

Comment: Nope. The link didn't help me. I have already tried acpi=force by editing  the entry in grub listing at the startup.

Comment: Guys, AFAI could understand, the problem is with some process which takes infinite time at the time of shutdown. It somehow is not being preempted by the kernel.

Comment: @noob00 I have updated my answer. please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well after some searching I came to know that , your problem belongs to Kernel.All you need to is simply update your Kernel, [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1888935) .

So you have to update your Kernel to  3.9, and Instructions are

Open your terminal and then paste this command to make sure that your system is up to date.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then

after doing update , restart your system to apply the changes and then change to tmp directory.

```
cd /tmp
```

Then for 32-bit Ubuntu Kernel is

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-rc8-raring/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900rc8-generic_3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835_i386.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-rc8-raring/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900rc8_3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-rc8-raring/linux-image-3.9.0-030900rc8-generic_3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835_i386.deb
```

for 64-bit

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-rc8-raring/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900rc8-generic_3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835_amd64.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-rc8-raring/linux-headers-3.9.0-030900rc8_3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835_all.deb http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-rc8-raring/linux-image-3.9.0-030900rc8-generic_3.9.0-030900rc8.201304211835_amd64.deb
```

Then install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then update your GRUB

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Now restart your system to apply the changes.

[Source](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/ready-for-linux-kernel-3-9-install-upgrade-your-kernel-in-ubuntu-13-04/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that too but no rescue. It stuck at the same point.

Comment: @noob00  , try another Kernel then ...as your message states there something you need to with kernel.http://kernel.ubuntu.com/testing/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the changes to your answer rajagenupula. Before trying to follow these steps, I had some inputs. I see a number of linux kernel updats listed at the grub menu. Each of the entry is a different kernel (right??) I already tried booting the system using these different kernels. But same problem was happening. Do you think, new kernel installation'd help??

Answer (score 1):

I've found these solutions for solving the problems with "improper shutdown" and "missing battery indicator" as follows:

System: lenovo G400

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Solution: booting with the `pci=noacpi` kernel parameter (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI)

To temporarily add `pci=noacpi' parameter to a kernel:

1. start your system press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
2. highlight the kernel you want, and press <kbd>e</kbd> key
3. to the line starting with `linux` add `pci=noacpi` at the end
4. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot

To make change permanent:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. have this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=noacpi"`
3. `sudo update-grub` then reboot

Answer (score 0):

have you tried shutting down from terminal using the command

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: yes I did try `sudo shutdown -P now` as well as `sudo shutdown -h now` . It  seems the kernel is  always in a  wait state because as soon as i press ctrl+alt+del it starts showiing other processes shutting down and restart the computer