# Can`t reboot sometimes (Ubuntu 13.10, AMD driver 13.10)

Tags: 13.10, reboot

When I shut down my notebook (Asus u38dt)- after Ubuntu logo the notebook freezes with black screen, power is still on and no reaction on any button (even no result with REISUB). The only way is to press (2-3 seconds) power button.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like ACPI.

Try this:

Type in terminal:

1. `sudo su`
2. `cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old`
3. `gedit /etc/default/grub`
4. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
5. Change this to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
6. Save the file and close the file.
7. Finally, in terminal: update-grub

Now, reboot your PC. It will hang again. Just manually power it off with the button. When you reboot again, it should work well.

I copied this guide from [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer). I couldn't put it in better words (commands).