# Ubuntu 13.10 won't shutdown/restart

Tags: shutdown, restart

I installed the 'new' Ubuntu 13.10, and it won't shutdown/restart from the menu. When pressing any of those buttons, Ubuntu will close some programs and then do nothing.

The only way that I've to shutdown/restart my PC is by blocking it, then moving the mouse so the black screen goes away, then changing user, and finally shutdown/restart from the login screen.

Anyway that I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the *do nothing* mean? Does the graphics stay? Does it show a purple screen only? Does some messages come up? And sorry but I don't know this slang term: *blocking the PC*, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to shutdown from the terminal,

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: I tried this before, it closed X and turned into a buggy terminal. I had to manually shutdown the PC from the case.

Comment: manually shutdown the pc means.

Comment: Long pressing the start button from the case until it shut it down, there was no other way.

Comment: did buggy terminal means virtual console?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a virtual console, but it was a console, the thing is that I couldn't do anything in there.

Comment: did you try `sudo shutdown -P now`?

Comment: It worked, but I wonder if there's a way to fix the menu buttons.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer