# Shutdown, Restart, Halt issues, not powering off system

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, restart

Before any one says search around, I have, to no avail. I can't seem to get it working after trying every fix out there.

So basically, when I turn off my laptop it shuts down fine but the last line is "System will now halt" but power never gets cut, I've tried shutdown -P and shutdown -h same result.

Then when I try restart it goes through the same process but hangs on "System will now restart"

But I can't figure it out, I am running full Ubuntu with no other Operating Systems.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer

Comment: Worked for a few days, but now after changing my Grub Background image and trying to change the text color it's back to not working, and yes I have made sure that the paramenter is still in the grub.cfg.