# Why does shutdown from a remote terminal fail to power off my machine?

Tags: command-line, ssh, shutdown, remote-access

I have noticed that if I `shutdown` Ubuntu 14.04 from a remote terminal via ssh and running `sudo shutdown now`, the machine does not power off.

If I use the GUI (shut down using Unity on the machine itself) then the machine does power off.

If I look on the console of the machine after issuing the remote shutdown, there are messages relating to modem manager which seems to keep restarting.

Is this a known issue?

---

Please note this is not a duplicate of [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer) as I'm using ssh to connect.

Comment: Are you using ssh?

Comment: @Tim yes I am connecting via ssh. I've added that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong commands, Try one of below:-

```
sudo shutdown -h now
sudo poweroff
sudo halt -p
sudo init 0
sudo shutdown -p now
```

For forced poweroff (not shutdown):-

```
  sudo poweroff -f
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all of these. The p needs to be capitalised i.e -P but still did not work. The only thing which worked was sudo poweroff

Comment: Please click on the tick next to the answer if it worked.