# Why is sudo -i then gedit better than sudo gedit?

Tags: sudo

I was looking at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/127022/300807) and came across this:

> 1. `sudo -i`  (to get a root shell, sudo gedit is not recommended)
> 2. `gedit /etc/default/grub`

I was wondering why `sudo gedit` is not recommended. In fact, it seems that it's better than the `sudo -i` method because a forgetful user may inadvertently run an undesired command as root, which can have a much larger consequence than the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. What should I do now? Should I delete the question or leave it open?

Comment: Never mind, I reloaded and a bar popped up above the question. I marked it as a duplicate via that.