# what's the problem: Computer not shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, shutdown, hp

I have installed Ubuntu(16.04) alongside Windows 7
I noticed that when I closed the computer from Ubuntu , the screen closes, but the computer will continue to engage, sometimes the screen remains dependent on this case

[image]

I always had to shut down the computer by pressing the power button for a few seconds.

I downloaded the system from the official site https://www.ubuntu.com/

My Laptop:

- HP Notebook 15-r208nk
- Processeur:Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3540 @ 2.16GHz × 4
- RAM: 4Gb
- Disk: 25.3 Gb

Thanks

Comment: I'll do my best; could you press f1 when it has been stuck shutting down and check the last a few lines, it should tell you what is holding it.

Comment: There is no response, the screen remained the same

Comment: i press Escape, the five last lines :
[OK] Removed slice system-system\x2dfsck.slice.
[OK] Stopped target Local File System (Pre).
[OK] Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[OK] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File System.
[OK] Reached target Shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this problem and the question is already answered here: [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)

This worked for me :o)

Comment: There are many answers, What is the best ??

Comment: The one answered by kubahaha that has 30 upvotes. I think I remember that this is the key: acpi=force

Comment: I  followed all point, but the same problem.