# Ubuntu 20.04 not fully shutdown, power light is still on. After system upgrade and uninstalling some snap programs

Tags: grub2, uefi, shutdown

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 and this problem happened. My laptop is unable to fully shutdown. There was no light at the keyboard or mouse, and the screen is completly black, but the power light is still on after waiting like 10-30 minutes. This made me to press power on/off button for 5 secnds to force shutdown...

I don't know what caused the problem because I also uninstalled some snap softwares which are: `Arduino`, `VLC` and `Octave GNU`.

I've tried all the solutions in other threads/websites but it didn't work:

- [Shutdown does not power off computer | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)
- [Ubuntu - Shutdown does not power-off (tried other solutions) | Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623159/ubuntu-shutdown-does-not-power-off-tried-other-solutions)
- [Fix Shutdown does not power off computer in Ubuntu 14.04 | Unixmen](https://www.unixmen.com/fix-shutdown-power-computer-ubuntu-14-04/)

I'm guessing that `Octave GNU` snap program that I uninstalled caused the problem, because when I uninstalled the software using the command `sudo snap remove --purge octave` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` it output this line in the terminal `Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`, so this makes me thinking it did something with my BIOS/EFI/GRUB settings while uninstalling.

But I'm still not sure if it's a bug from the upgrade after running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

**UPDATE**
I tried booting into dual-boot Windows 10 and then powering off, I didn't facing the shutting down problem like in Ubuntu, so I think BIOS firmware and settings are still intact.

Please take a look at the details below for the insight.
And thank you in advance for your help!

**Output of Journalctl**
`sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`

```
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-scrcpy-351.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for scrcpy, revision 351.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-snap\x2dstore-547.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 547.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-snap\x2dstore-558.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 558.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-snapd-13640.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 13640.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-snapd-14066.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 14066.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d6\x2dstable-14.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for wine-platform-6-stable, revision 14.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d6\x2dstable-8.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for wine-platform-6-stable, revision 8.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-271.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for wine-platform-runtime, revision 271.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-273.mount: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for wine-platform-runtime, revision 273.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Dec 02 10:59:03 vivobook-asus systemd-journald[270]: Journal stopped
```

**Info from Boot Repair tool**

```
boot-repair-4ppa130                                              [20211202_1104]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================



/usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd_terminal.sh: line 177: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
sda5,
using the following options:        sda1/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups


/boot/efi added in sda5/fstab
rm /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Quantity of real Windows: 1
sda5/boot/efi not empty

================= Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of sda5 ==================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.13

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)

uname -r
5.11.0-41-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS CurrentSession entry (sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1947310080 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be 
    found at this location.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS CurrentSession on sda5
OS#2:   Windows 7 on sda3

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic root=UUID=e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528 ro quiet splash acpi=force vt.handoff=7


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/Boot/bootx64.efi
85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   sda1/Boot/fbx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   sda1/Boot/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda1/Boot/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
7f59d0c2d9947fcb14eb3bd9c7c1096b   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
a9ce1daef4035d5351088da868df834a   sda1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda5    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda4    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 18D6D0EC-9E3E-4AD3-9DBE-CCCB8DC07124
           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1        2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
sda2      534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda3      567296  534244750  533677455 254.5G Microsoft basic data
sda4  1952192512 1953523711    1331200   650M Windows recovery environment
sda5   534245376 1952192511 1417947136 676.1G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:274GB:273GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:274GB:1000GB:726GB:ext4::;
4:1000GB:1000GB:682MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                
├─sda1 vfat     361C-4F5E                            603921a5-1204-42d7-bf06-2146df93d363 SYSTEM   EFI system partition
├─sda2                                               eb42d3a0-ed64-4228-8c71-fdb968fd06c6          Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda3 ntfs     ECAC1F47AC1F0C28                     ca3bcd2f-8e10-4152-98f8-83c2774fd111 OS       Basic data partition
├─sda4 ntfs     002A80422A803726                     04e228e1-ac30-4c98-8ef3-2dd013f9b09b RECOVERY Basic data partition
└─sda5 ext4     e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528 6702620d-1b8e-4671-9b6b-5d186bbbdd82          

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
sda3               74.1G  71% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda4              199.9M  69% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
sda5                553G  12% /

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda3              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda4              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5              rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528 root hd0,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-41-generic   e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-40-generic   e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528
Windows Boot Manager (on sda1)   osprober-efi-361C-4F5E
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=e779c5ec-3c0d-404f-ad16-3dae57313528 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=361C-4F5E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 358.915363312 = 385.382436864  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 561.594921112 = 603.007954944  boot/vmlinuz                                   3
 565.782417297 = 607.504244736  boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-40-generic                 2
 561.594921112 = 603.007954944  boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic                 3
 565.782417297 = 607.504244736  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 561.919372559 = 603.356332032  boot/initrd.img                                3
 566.224040985 = 607.978434560  boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic              2
 561.919372559 = 603.356332032  boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic              3
 566.224040985 = 607.978434560  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 ส.ค.  12 16:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 พ.ย.  13  2020 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 ก.ค.  31  2020 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 ก.ค.  31  2020 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 ก.ค.  31  2020 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 ก.ค.  31  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 ก.ค.  31  2020 41_custom
```

**System info from dmidecode** `sudo dmidecode`

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.
Table at 0x000EACC0.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: X409BA.301
    Release Date: 08/24/2020
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 8192 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.12

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X409BA_M409BA
    Version: 1.0       
    Serial Number: KAN0CV110255438
    UUID: 719b10c7-1814-2f46-9d54-5217eab272a0
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number:  
    Family: VivoBook

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: X409BA
    Version: 1.0       
    Serial Number: KA42NBCV00EKLYMB
    Asset Tag: ATN12345678901234567
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: MIDDLE              
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: 1.0       
    Serial Number: KAN0CV110255438
    Asset Tag: No Asset Tag
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: NA

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 CACHE
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 160 kB
    Maximum Size: 160 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Pipeline Burst
    Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
    Speed: 1 ns
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 2-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 CACHE
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 1024 kB
    Maximum Size: 1024 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Pipeline Burst
    Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
    Speed: 1 ns
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 10, 26 bytes
On Board Device 1 Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description: VGA
On Board Device 2 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: GLAN
On Board Device 3 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: WLAN
On Board Device 4 Information
    Type: Sound
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Audio CODEC
On Board Device 5 Information
    Type: SATA Controller
    Status: Enabled
    Description: SATA Controller
On Board Device 6 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: USB 2.0 Controller
On Board Device 7 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: USB 3.0 Controller
On Board Device 8 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: SMBus Controller
On Board Device 9 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Card Reader
On Board Device 10 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Cmos Camera
On Board Device 11 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Bluetooth

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: kPJ-+7X7+EfTa
    String 2: jTyRUBSNi7Ydf
    String 3: fCrOzJ6x1i-eh
    String 4:  
    String 5: 90NB0PL1-M00260

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: SMI:00B26C
    Option 2: DSN:                                
    Option 3: DSN:                                
    Option 4: DSN:                                

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0027
    Partition Width: 1

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0027
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: A1_Manufacturer0
    Serial Number: A1_SerialNum0
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: A1_PartNum0
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0027
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 2400 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Micron
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: 4ATF51264HZ-2G6E1   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 1866 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x002A
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0028
    Partition Row Position: Unknown

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: P0
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: A-Series
    Manufacturer: AuthenticAMD
    ID: FF FB 8B 17 00 0F 67 00
    Signature: Family 11, Model 15, Stepping 15
    Flags:
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        PSN (Processor serial number present and enabled)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
    Version: AMD A4-9125 RADEON R3, 4 COMPUTE CORES 2C+2G   
    Voltage: 1.1 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 2300 MHz
    Current Speed: 2300 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: None
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0004
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 2
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: @Community I know you are a bot but for those seeing this thread, I would like to know how to fix the laptop not properly shutdown and the power is still on. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About a week ago, I started suffering from this exact problem, and I found out the hard way it was occurring.  I closed my laptop lid, set the device on my bed, and walked away.  Hours later, I came back, and the spot on the bed where I laid the laptop was physically very hot.  I opened the laptop, and the screen was black and would not respond to anything.  I had to force shut down the device.  I assumed it was a fluke, but a few days later, I found not only closing the lid would not work, but the shutdown and reboot would not work either.

I googled a lot of solutions, and none of them worked.

What did work for me was degrading the current kernel.  I must have upgraded it the previous week.

**Past configuration:**

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Release:    20.04

Codename:   focal

**Kernel: 5.11.0-41-generic**

**Current configuration:**

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Release:    20.04

Codename:   focal

**Kernel: 5.11.0-40-generic**

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The working version of the kernel is very helpful

Comment: I confirm that the last working version of the kernel is 5.11.0-40... is there a solution?

Comment: Bug in kernel 5.13 and AMD APUs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958519

Answer (score 1):

Installing kernel `5.11.0-27-generic` on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS also resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually experienced exactly the same behaviour after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. I didn’t delete any packages in the past days, so at least you can rule out that uninstalling the software caused this issue. That the issue did not persist after shutting down from Windows does indeed hint towards an OS problem. Hopefully this bug will be removed with the next patch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's helpufl that you encountered the problem even if you didn't uninstall some packages. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04.03, but the problem still persists, so I tried reinstall Ubuntu with the version 18.04 and all the problems've gone. This is for sure the kernel problem with the 20.04 update.

Answer (score 0):

I now know what is the problem with the shutting down issue. Yesterday, I tried booting into dual boot Windows 10 and there was no shutdown issue.

then I went back to Ubuntu and tried re-installing `grub` and repair the boot related stuffs using [boot repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and the problem still persists, so the problem is not with the `grub`.

I then tried reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 to see if there are some system configs messed up, but the problem still persists, so the problem is for sure with the kernel itself.

So I tried reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04, and all of the problems have gone.

Now it's clear that the minor/patch update of Ubuntu 20.04 messing up with the kernel and it causes the problems.