# Computer doesn't completely shut off when pressing shutdown

Tags: grub2, shutdown

The title explains it all, when I press the shutdown button the screen goes black so the OS shuts down, but the fans keep running.

I already tried editing stuff in /etc/default/grub as said in other questions like this one, but even though I tried everything nothing seems to be working.

I have the latest LTS version so 20.04 iirc

I did everything I could find here:
[Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)

Comment: There's not much *actionable* detail here, as any suggestion someone might make has a high probability of being something that doesn't work given that you've "tried everything". Could you [edit] your question to help narrow down the possibilities by including: (0) the brand and model of computer you're using (1) some of the things you've tried, with specific examples. With this additional information, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: Alright I edited the post, hopefully this info is enough

Comment: Brand/model is a very important info that's still missing. And some almost 10 years old answers are hardly relevant and, even worse, some are hardware specific and others are RELEASE specific. Applying either can't possibly work. That's the problem of doing stuff one doesn't understand.