# Remote reboot over ssh does not restart

Tags: 12.04, ssh, shutdown, reboot, restart

I would like to remotely reboot my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server via ssh. I do `sudo reboot` and I loose connection and the server connection does not reappear. It does not ping.

When I go the the physical computer with a screen attached I see a black screen and hear that the server is still on. I do a hard power off (press power on button for a few seconds) and the server halts. After I press power on the server boots with no problem.

As far as I remember the remote reboot has previously worked on that server.

I wonder if `sudo reboot &` will help? I suppose I could also try `sudo shutdown -r` and see if that does any difference.

I have listed an excerpt of `/etc/log/syslog` below. The last thing it records is the stopping of the logging.

```
Oct 24 10:14:49 servername kernel: [1354427.594709] init: cron main process (1060) killed by TERM signal
Oct 24 10:14:49 servername kernel: [1354427.594908] init: irqbalance main process (1080) killed by TERM signal
Oct 24 10:14:49 servername kernel: [1354427.595299] init: tty1 main process (1424) killed by TERM signal
Oct 24 10:14:49 servername kernel: [1354427.637747] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (20873) terminated with status 1
Oct 24 10:14:49 servername kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Oct 24 10:14:49 servername rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="876" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Oct 24 10:25:34 servername kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Oct 24 10:25:34 servername rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="862" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Comment: Have you tried both methods you're suggesting ?

Comment: Not yet. For every reboot I have to walk to another building to get it restarted.

Comment: I now I tried `sudo reboot &` and it did not work.

Comment: I now also tried `sudo shutdown -r now`  non-remotely, - and it did not work. My last messages are `Unmounting local filesystems`, `Will now restart...` and `[a number] Restarting system` which it obviously doesn't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have had the same problem: [Why can't I restart/shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7114/why-cant-i-restart-shutdown)

Colin Watson suggests trying different parameters for `reboot=` in grub.

Comment: And now with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=b"` in `/etc/default/grub` it seems to work! At least two tests with `sudo shutdown -r now` got it right back.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try *sudo init6*

For more evaluation, you should update the dmesg and syslog outputs , when the server restart.

Comment: I have now tried "sudo init 6" in vain.

Comment: I do not understand "you should update the dmesg and syslog outputs". I think it is after the logs are shut down that the problem begins.