# Shutdown over SSH

Tags: ssh, shutdown, sudo

I just installed a fresh ubuntu server 12.04. I log in over SSH and use `sudo -s` to get root access. Then I use `shutdown now` and the server closes the connection. I cannot access the server over SSH, FTP or HTTP anymore, it appears to be off. *But it isn't*. The server stays on, without being useful. Why? How can I shutdown the server with SSH?

Comment: Possible dulpicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/205674/remote-reboot-over-ssh-does-not-restart?rq=1

Comment: no, rebooting does work

Comment: I don't think this issue has anything to do with SSH. It just seems stuck in the shutdown procedure somewhere, or, the ACPI command isn't perfoming an actual power off (just a halt). Do you have physical access to a console of that server to clarify? (or remote-KVM, serial console, etc.) Oh, and have you tried adding the `-h` flag to `shutdown` like this? `shutdown -h now`

Comment: It shouldn't be stuck, it's a clean installation with only LAMP installed. `shutdown -h now` works (as does `poweroff`, mentioned in the first answer)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try this command over SSH:

```
sudo poweroff
```

If you want to just send this command over SSH and authenticate in one go, append the command to the regular SSH command:

```
ssh -t <options> <user>@<hostname> sudo poweroff
```

Thanks [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) for [suggesting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251148/shutdown-over-ssh/251160?noredirect=1#comment1395816_251160) the `-t` option to allow for entering the sudo password.

Comment: Also you can specify password: ssh user@host 'echo password | sudo -S poweroff'

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to specify passwords in commands like that (plain text). I've removed the SSH part from your question as the `poweroff` part is what it is about (and a good suggestion). Removed my earlier comment crititizing that now. +1

Comment: @gertvdijk - If I do not put the password in the ssh command, how can I shut down the machine in just one line of command?

Comment: @Casper Added :)

Comment: @gertvdijk If `sudo` wants to ask for a password, perhaps `-t` would be needed (or an askpass program)

Comment: I suggest ssh root@ip halt which is similar to `-t` if you are allowed to login as root. Why does `'halt'` with quotation marks not work? I pass a string which is a cmd to ssh. Maybe it is interpreted as `string`.