# `shutdown -r now` command completely shutting down instead of restarting

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server, shutdown, reboot

Hi we've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto a new server. It's on a SuperMicro X9SCA-f Motherboard .

Now we're aiming to locate this in a remote server room - however when we execute a `shutdown -r now` the system completly shuts down and has to be restarted using the power button!!
I cant find any BIOS setting that seems applicable.

Any help/pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "reboot" ?

Comment: Behaviour of shutdown is a setting in Ubuntu not in BIOS.

Comment: As a workaround tour could just use 'sudo reboot'.

Comment: reboot does exactly the same :-(

Comment: While this is not a duplicate but the opposite from [why-cant-i-restart-shutdown](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7114/why-cant-i-restart-shutdown) the answers there might provide a clue for you too.

Comment: I am really curious to know Why 'shutdown -r' doesn't reboot the server !! Can anyone tell us why ?

Comment: did you happen to try `sudo init 6`?  That should also force the restart.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that perhaps there's something reinterpreting your command and adding some extra switches? As in, an alias in a ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: Something is going on here, it looks like halt is being called instead of reboot. Please use strace to log all the actors on behalf of shutdown. <pre>
strace -f /sbin/shutdown -r > /root/shutdown-trace.out 2>&1
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

Restart using `init`:

```
sudo init 6
```

The `init 6` command gracefully reboots the system running all the `K*` shutdown scripts first, before rebooting.  The `reboot` command does a very quick reboot.  It doesn’t execute any kill scripts, but just unmounts filesystems and restarts the system.

Comment: This is incorrect. `reboot` is only more abrupt than `init 6` or `shutdown -r now` if you use `reboot --force` (or equivalently `reboot -f`). Normal operation of `reboot` (when run simply with `sudo reboot`) is to invoke `shutdown`, which in turn invokes `init` to change the runlevel. See [`man 8 reboot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/reboot.8.html) and [`man 8 shutdown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) for details. In other words, it is simply false to say that `K*` scripts are not run when rebooting with `sudo reboot`. They are.