# Problem with shutting down in Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 64-bit

Tags: 13.04, gnome, 64-bit, shutdown

I have a laptop running Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 64-bit. Whenever I click on the 'Power Off' button from the menu on the top panel and then click 'Power Off', the laptop always restarts (does not SHUT DOWN). Please help me. I also set the power button action in the Gnome Tweak tool to 'Shutdown'. Also, this does not happen everytime. I think it might be some bug.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running

```
sudo halt
```

in a terminal?

If that works, try using something like Create Launcher and having the command be

```
sudo halt.
```

Good luck.

Comment: Using 'sudo halt', the OS did kind of shut down, but after reaching the last screen where it shows default gnome wallpaper and all icons disappear, it got stuck there and I again had to switch it off manually using power switch on my laptop.

Comment: @nisargshah95 That's what halt is supposed to do. It's somewhat like the "It is now safe to shutdown your computer" prompts from Windows 95.

Comment: @Seth Oh, did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the answers proposed in

[Ubuntu 13.04 will not shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288736/ubuntu-13-04-will-not-shutdown)

They are most likely the same problem.

Comment: The above question holds when I use 'sudo halt'. But I still haven't found an answer as to why sometimes clicking 'Power Off' restarts my laptop.