# Ubuntu 15.04 doesn't shutdown properly on MacBook Pro 5,3

Tags: shutdown, 15.04, macbook-pro

After about 2 weeks of trial and error trying to get this lovely OS working on my Mac, I still have a few issues:

I can't figure out how to make f1-f12 work as standard function keys w/o holding fn.

I have to boot in Legacy mode in ReFind with apci=off in GRUB.

And most importantly, shutting down gets me as a black screen with the message "[2501.546937] reboot: System halted," with the underscore blinking underneath, from which point I have to hold down the power button. I'm guessing this might be due to booting with apci=off.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask *one question*, so you can receive *one answer*.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  **;-)** So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: I actually solved most of those, and reposted a question for the one I had left :-)

Comment: **Voted to close question** as all symptoms went away (see above comment)

Comment: [This other answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/412969) worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded drivers from Mactel support, now able to boot in EFI mode and shutdown works properly.