# Lenovo Yoga s940 + Ubuntu 19.10 power off not working

Tags: shutdown, lenovo, 19.10

Tried a lot of options described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632591/system-does-not-power-off-on-poweroff-just-halts), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7114/why-cant-i-restart-shutdown), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer) and on [other forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1776484.html) but neither worked for me .

Tried a number of grub parameters including `acpi=force reboot=acpi` as well as all sorts of `reboot` params as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/13193/953011) answer.

There are no problems with reboot however, only with power off (system shuts down to a black screen and then I have to hold the HW shutdown button to switch the computer off)

Any suggestions/thoughts on how to fix this specific problem?

Comment: please give a reason for downvote so together we can make askubuntu a better place to find answers for everyone. Silently downvoting doesn't benefit anyone really. Is it not clear? Or not suited for this site? I'm not getting what's wrong with it - I have a specific problem that I'm trying to solve for a few days and asking for help. Please, if you can't help, at least share your thoughts on why you think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: Do you wait two minutes before long pressing the power button?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, yep, tried to wait for like 30 minutes without success

Comment: Wanted to comment on the downvote that was initially present when I first saw this question: Check out https://idownvotedbecau.se for reason candidates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

It appeared that this problem was caused by the fact that I've switched off the intel graphic driver with `nomodset` boot parameter while I was trying to fix laggish/screen redraw problem. I was able to fix the original problem with `i915.enable_psr=0` boot parameter so no need for `nomodset` anymore and this problem went away. I'll leave it here anyways in case it might help someone.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

This boot command finally fixed the problem for me:

```
pci=nommconf
```

Here is how one can add it:

1. in terminal type `sudo -i` (enter root shell)
2. then `gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
4. Change to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nommconf"`
5. Save and close the file.
6. again, in terminal `update-grub`
7. and finally `exit` (to end the root shell)

Hope that helps someone